# Say or speak, which is the correct verb in the context?

Tags: verbs

What would be correct?

1. I'd like to ***say*** the first two paragraphs from the speech.
2. I'd like to ***speak*** the first two paragraphs from the speech.

It's not to be read out from a written sheet, please note; it's to be memory based. Any other verb which would more appropriate may also be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

"Say" would be more common than "speak".

It would depend on the context, but I can imagine something like:

> I'd like to **share** the first two paragraphs from the speech.

Or perhaps something like this would be appropriate in certain contexts:

> I'd like to **recite** the first two paragraphs from the speech.

Answer (score 0):

***Recite*** is the word I'd normally use.